# Creating a procedure in oracle that prints multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that compiles but when it runs I get an error that the "exact fetch returns more than the requested number of rows" the code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_details(
   in_account_nbr NUMBER
)
 IS 
     r_transaction transaction%ROWTYPE;
 BEGIN

 SELECT * 
 INTO r_transaction
 FROM transaction
 WHERE account_nbr = in_account_nbr;

--print it out
dbms_output.put_line(r_transaction.Account_Nbr || r_transaction.Tx_amount);

END;
```

What do I have to change so it will print all the rows where the user-specified number is the same as one of the ones in the table

Comment: you can use a cursor along with a loop.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Would I put the cursor on r-transaction? and is there anything about the current code I would have to change besides adding a cursor and a loop?

Answer (score 1):

As @BarbarosÖzhan said, you can turn your query into a cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_details(
   in_account_nbr NUMBER
)
IS 
BEGIN

  FOR r IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM transaction
    WHERE account_nbr = in_account_nbr
  )
  LOOP

    --print it out
    dbms_output.put_line(r.Account_Nbr || r.Tx_amount);

  END LOOP;
END print_details;
/
```

Notice that you don't need to declare a rowtype variable )and in fact, even if you do, the loop variable would override it).

In general you should avoid `*` - you can change the select list to only include the columns you actually need to refer to within the loop. Here that's only really `Tx_amount`, since you already know the `Account_Nbr` value from the parameter. And you probably want some whitespace at least between the two values when you print them.

```
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT Tx_amount
    FROM transaction
    WHERE account_nbr = in_account_nbr
  )
  LOOP

    --print it out
    dbms_output.put_line(in_account_bbr || ': ' || r.Tx_amount);

  END LOOP;
```

Using `dbms_output` for anything except ad hoc code and debugging isn't ideal though; you have no control over whether someone calling this procedure will see the output. It depends on their client and its settings. Presumably this is an exercise though.